# Register in a WebApplication using GMAIL,Facebook logins

Tags: java, jsp

Creating a WebApplication using Java JSP which will have User Registration.
Many applications allow users to login using gmail, facebook credentials.
Wat APIs are used in such scenarios.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to use OAuth 2.0 with Google and Facebook APIs.

You should look at this: [OAuth 2.0 with Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web), and that: [OAuth 2.0 with Google API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).